# what possile balancing method can I apply on a imbalanced data set?

Tags: r, dataset, machine-learning, classification

Im trying to solve one classification problem from de UCI database repository.  https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Student+Performance
Unfortunately (or fortunately) I've noticed that my dataset is imbalanced
( I've propose the problem like a 5 classes one ( according to the final mark reached by the pupil) ,and so..:

- If student gets a mark from 0 to 7 => class 1 [FAIL(E)]
- If student gets a mark from 8 to 9 => class 2 [SUFFICIENT(D)]
- If student gets a mark from 10 to 11 => class 3 [GOOD(C)]
- If student gets a mark from 12 to 15 => class 4 [NOTABLE(B)]
- Ifstudent gets a mark from 16 to 19 => class 5 [OUTSTANDING(A)]

My problem is that, as I said, data are imbalanced, so I want to balance it.

I've thought-out about aplying some kind of undersamplimg method,  but my dataset has only 649 instances so I think removing some of them is not the best idea. Then I thought about doing some oversampling, in order to replicate  some of the minority class examples and then get classes balanced, but I'm still unsure if that could be nice.

I would be very grateful if you could give me a hand with this.
Its the first time I face a real problem with imbalanced data.

Comment: So? It's unbalenced. What the problem? Even if this does get migrated to CV.com, the stats-guys are still going to want to know what methods you propose and that will determine the necessary corrections (if any) are needed.

Comment: Some methods will handle unbalanced data just fine.